# Is it better to use separate tables to store rows that apply to "a more general classification", or are nullable columns suitable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am building a database for a company that sells warranty packages.  There are a number of attributes associated to each package that factor into the final price.  For example, the age of the vehicle.  Prices for the age of the vehicle need to be set at the package level, but also can be set at the state/province or dealership level.  This is in order to allow for overriding the base package pricing

I would like to know if the table example below is an acceptable practice or is building separate tables for state/province and dealership pricing a better decision.

```
Id              | int   | NOT NULL
PackageId       | int   | NOT NULL
StateProvinceId | int   | NULL
DealershipId    | int   | NULL
MinAge          | int   | NOT NULL
MaxAge          | int   | NOT NULL
Premium         | money | NOT NULL
```

When a customer is purchasing a warranty, I need to prioritize the qualification by 1) dealership, 2) state/province, and 3) package.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, a dealership will always be associated to a state/province in the database.  No, I can set a price strictly at the dealership level that only impacts a specific dealership, but all the other dealerships in the same state/province will receive the package price.

Comment: Make sure to add updated context/information into the question itself, showing example cases as appropriate. It is more visible that way.

Comment: This is a design question that is difficult to answer without knowing the framework that you are using or how this type of problem is solved in other parts of your application. Having two fields is sort of ok, but you will have to hardcode the priority between them.